# Run worker thread one after another

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, synchronization

I have two worker threads which I want to run sequentially ,thread1 & thread2 one after another. In order to control them I am using two CEvent(MFC api) synchronization object. My current implementation(below) is not perfect that why some time it enters into deadlock conditions.Please suggest me how I can improve my code.

```
    //My Code
vector<MyClass> globalVector; // global variable being accessed across two thread
CEvent event1 = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,TRUE,"Event1");
CEvent event2 = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,TRUE,"Event2");

int main()
{

  ResetEvent(event1); // to make sure thread1 do not start immediately
  AfxBeginThread(WorkerThread1,NULL);
  WaitForSingleObject(event1,INFINITE); // thread2 waits until first twenty iteration   
  AfxBeginThread(WorkerThread2,NULL);

  return 0;
}

//Thread1
UNIT WorkerThread1(LPVOID lp)
{
    int i=1;
    while(i<=100)
    {
        ResetEvent(event1);
        WaitForSingleObject(event2,INFINITE);

        //Do some stuff
        MyClass temp;
        globalVector.push_back( temp);

        if(i%20==0)
        {
            SetEvent(event1);
            ResetEvent(event2);
        }

        i++;
    }
 return 0;
}

//Thread2
UNIT WorkerThread2(LPVOID lp)
{
    while(globalVector.size()>0)
    {
        for(vector<MyClass>::iterator it = globalVector.begin();it<globalVector.end();it++)
        {
            //Do some stuff
        }
        //Delete all elements from globalVector
        globalVector.clear();
        SetEvent(event2);
        WaitForSingleObject(event1,INFINITE);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Ideally I want the two thread to run as follow:-

for i = 1 to 20.

Thread1().
Thread2().

for i = 21 to 40.

Thread1().
Thread2().

for i = 41 to 60.

Thread1().
Thread2().

for i = 61 to 80.

Thread1()
Thread2()

for i = 81 to 100

Thread1().
Thread2().

Comment: Since you aren't guarding your *globalVector*, *thread1* and *thread2* cannot run at the same time. Since you also require *thread2* to run only after *thread1* has finished processing, there is really just a single option left: Throw out *thread2* and move its processing code into *thread1*.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to just use 1 event, set signals that the global vector changes.
You have to use a synchronisation like a CCricticalSection to prevent concurrent access to the global vector.

1. Start the threads
2. Thread 1 locks the global vector pushes some data into it sets the event and releases the lock.
3. Thread 2 just waits for the event. It locks the global vector. pops retrieves one element. And if the vector is empty resets the Event. Thread 2 unlocks the vector and processes the data.

Comment: I will try using CCricticalSection instead of event2 but please clear my doubt that how to make sure that thread1 do not renters after step no 2.

Comment: Where is the problem. You sample doesn't explain why thread 1 must pause until thread 2 is done.